# Call function with dynamically generated name in Freemarker

Tags: java, html, freemarker

Am I able to call a function from Java Object that has generated name from a few strings? In my example it's a simple getter. Just curious.

Process is a Java object like this:

```
public class Process {
   private int number = 0;

   public int getNumber() {
       return this.number;
   }

   public String getPropertyName() {
       return "number";
   }
}
```

Let's say we passed the Process object into freemarker template as a variable **process** with something like this:

> return Results.html().render("process", new Process());

Now we have a html page containing the piece of code below. The method I have in mind should do something like this example (*the example does NOT work!*):

```
<#assign methodName = "process.get" + process.getPropertyName()?cap_first + "()">
<input name="${process.getPropertyName()}" type="number" value="${methodName}"/>
```

The result interpreted in html is this:

> `<input name="number" type="number" value="process.getNumber()"/>`

But it's just a string and it's not interpreted in freemarker template as a value stored inside the method.

What do you think, **is there a way to achieve this**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to dynamically access a field, then you can write it like that:

```
<input name="${process.propertyName}" type="number" value="${process[process.propertyName]}"/>
```

But if you really want to call method, then you can try with [`eval`](http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_builtins_expert.html#ref_builtin_eval):

```
<input name="${process.getPropertyName()}" type="number" value="${methodName?eval}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks, that's it! Maybe it was just too late to find the solution myself ;)